# firebase auth in google chrome

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

firebase google authenticate method fails in google chrome. I see these two messages in dev tools console.

```
OPTIONS https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/getProjectConfig?key=my-app-key&cb=1514367607784 net::ERR_QUIC_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Info: The current domain is not authorized for OAuth operations. This will prevent signInWithPopup, signInWithRedirect, linkWithPopup and linkWithRedirect from working. Add your domain (my-web-domain.com) to the OAuth redirect domains list in the Firebase console -> Auth section -> Sign in method tab.
```

A domain entry is set in sign in method firebase console.
In google console (api and services) there is my firebase web api key with restrictions = none, as well as *OAuth2* entry with the correct client id and client secret matching the ones of my firebase project shown in firebase console. The domain is also set in *Authorized JavaScript origins* section. Authorized redirect URI section has an entry `https://fbase-unique-name.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/handler`

As far as I noticed this started failing a week or so ago and only happens on chrome. I've tried on chromium, firefox, egde, brave in linux and windows and it works.
Thanks in advance

Comment: I wonder if this is specific to an SDK version? Seems like a pretty odd combination of factors.

Comment: I've tried the latest and several older ones, all fail with the latest google chrome.

Comment: Working for me on the latest Chrome with Google Auth. https://kato-sandbox.firebaseapp.com/

Comment: @Kato, your sample app fails as well as mine.
`A network error (such as timeout, interrupted connection or unreachable host) has occurred.`- the error message on chrome Version 63.0.3239.108 (Official Build) (64-bit). Or `Info: The current domain is not authorized for OAuth operations. This will prevent signInWithPopup, signInWithRedirect, linkWithPopup and linkWithRedirect from working. Add your domain (kato-sandbox.firebaseapp.com) to the OAuth redirect domains list in the Firebase console -> Auth section -> Sign in method tab.
Xg @ iframe.js:181` when from incognito tab.

Comment: Retry in incognito? Could be an extension or caching issue. Working for me with 63.0.3239.108 (Official Build) (64-bit).

Comment: Probably a Chrome flag causes the error: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/xKFfhDvhjU8

Comment: Try resetting your chrome browser settings and try again. Also test on a different machine with the same browser version to confirm this is isolated to your current browser.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem, only happened in latest chrome, but my error is

`auth/network-request-failed`

My solution is to download the beta chrome channel on https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/beta.html and somehow the error doesn't popup anymore, not sure what caused the problem though.